# How do you expand delimited rows in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Emails                                                   | Data
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
userA@email.com;userB@email.com;userC@email.com          | Foo
userB@email.com                                          | Bar
```

I want to parse out the delimited emails into their own rows such that it looks something like this:

```
   Emails                                                   | Data
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    userA@email.com                                          | Foo
    userB@email.com                                          | Foo
    userC@email.com                                          | Foo
    userB@email.com                                          | Bar
```

I know there is a string_split function, but it would only work on the first column. I need some kind of join for this.

EDIT: Yes I know it breaks normal form, but bigquery for instance has an "unnest" function and has arrays as a datatype.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is ancient and SQL Server has better options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the more recent versions of SQL Server, you can use [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select s.value as email, t.data
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.emails, ';') s;
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I need to read up on cross apply

Comment: @starbyone You also need to read up on First Normal Form

Comment: @Charlieface this is how the data comes in raw format (the user has a single input field to add one or more email-addresses). I do not have access to the backend code